# Add location to a Google+ Story

Tags: google-plus, location

My story currently has a location but it is wrong and the options it offers in the edit dropdown are not right either.

How can I add a location in a Google+ story?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google+ Stories only let you select locations they suggest. You can [send feedback to Google+](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1678224) if you would like to see that changed.